# Why can't I use the select function in Kendo UI grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When I use this function, it gives me an error.

```
 var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
 var currentSelection = grid.select();
```

and Firefox shows the error:[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure you have the [Selectable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder#methods-Selectable) property set on your grid.

```
<%:Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
.Name("grid")
.Selectable()
.DataSource(dataSource =>
    // configure the data source
    dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))
)
%>
```